# Display a gif until content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sorry if this has already been answered numerous times, as i've seen a lot have, just not exactly what i'm looking for.

So I have just a basic HTML page looking like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Loading GIF</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="mainImg.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    #loader {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 9999;
      background: url('flash_loading.gif') center no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
  <section id="loader">
    I'm loading..
  </section>

 <div>LOADS OF IMAGES AND CONTENT</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my JS file looks like (I was just testing different methods):

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
   console.info("Image loaded !");
   //do something...
}

image.src = "http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2010/08/196550,xcitefun-people-place-5.jpg";
```

My question, how, in jQuery can I actually load in a loading gif until everything on the page has loaded, the images, content everything?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe just put the picture over the page by default and then remove it on window.onload

Comment: Don't you see the loading gif in your code?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Initially bind the loading image inside a div. Let's its visibility property be true and then at DOM ready you can set that div property visiblity to false.

Answer (score 0):

Try

html:

```
<section class="loader">
    I'm loading..
</section>
```

css:

```
section.loader {
    background: url('flash_loading.gif') no-repeat 50% 50%;
    transition: background-color 0;
}

section.loader body {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("section").removeClass("loader");
```

Or:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Loading GIF</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="mainImg.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <style>
  #loading {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      position: fixed;
      display: block;
      opacity: .9;
      background-color: #fff;
      z-index: 99;
      text-align: center;
   }
    #loader-image {
      position: absolute;
      top: 250px;
      left: 550px;
      z-index: 600          
    }
 </style>

 <div id="loader">
  <img id="loader-image" src="flash_loading.gif" alt="I'm loading.."/>
 </div>

 <div>LOADS OF IMAGES AND CONTENT</div>

</div>
</body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function() {
  $('#loader').hide();
});

</script>


</html>
```